# Can i filter my tin-can-statements with score parameter?

Tags: javascript, tin-can-api, lrs

I 'm implementing a course with javascript which sends tin-can-api statements to an LRS. When i use the getStatements function to get some back, it seems I cannot use the parameter score in order to retrieve only the statements with a specific score. Is it so by tincan api, or am i doing something wrong?
Thanks in advance!
K.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a limitation of Tin Can/xAPI, specifically the [Statement Resource](https://github.com/adlnet/xAPI-Spec/blob/master/xAPI-Communication.md#213-get-statements), which has no support for querying by score.

The best you can do is to retrieve all relevant statements, and then filter them in JavaScript.